# Arabic language - UnicodeDecodeError in Python 2.7

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I wrote this code to process Arabic language by python

```
 import codecs
 file = codecs.open("C:\Python27\CCA_raw_utf8.txt","r","utf-8")
 text= file.read()
 ####################################

 print "\n "," --------------------------------------------"

 text=text[1:]
 words=text.split()

 for w in words:
    if w == unicode ("الشيخ","utf-8"):
    print w
```

but it doesn't work, and it raise an error:

```
if w == unicode ("الشيخ","utf-8"):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 0: invalid    continuation byte "
```

Why is my program gives this result and how can we fix that??

Comment: Curious here, in my IDE it says `unsupported characters in input`..

Answer (score 1):

you may need to use a terminal that supports unicode characters.  The code `unicode("الشيخ","utf-8")` works in osx.

Try using IDLE or some other IDE/terminal.

Comment: I suggest using Console2, it is absolutely fantastic with foreign characters (I use it constantly)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your text editor is not storing and showing the text in UTF-8 but is using another encoding. Try using a Unicode literal instead:

```
if w == u"الشيخ":
```

If that still doesn't work you'll need to figure out which encoding your editor is using and put that in place of `"utf-8"`.

Comment: @user2913962 you just have to know. What OS and editor are you using? If it's Windows, what language variant is installed?

Comment: @user2913962 in that case try using `"windows-1256"` as the parameter to `unicode`.

Comment: @user2913962 can you be more specific? I doubt that it's the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link. I think it's useful for this situation.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError